# How do I parse a quoted string inside another string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing

I want to extract the quoted substrings from inside a string. This is an example:

```
string = 'aaaa' + string_var_x + 'bbbb' + string_var_y
```

The output after parsing should be:

```
["'aaaa'", "'bbbb'"]
```

The initial solution was to `string.scan /'\w'/` which is almost ok.

Still I can't get it working on more complex string, as it's implied that inside `'...'` there can be any kind of characters (including numbers, and `!@#$%^&*()` whatever).

Any ideas?

I wonder if there's some way to make `/'.*'/` working, but make it less greedy?

Comment: @elusive's answer will do it. Notice the use of `?` after the `*`? That's how to make it not be greedy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lazy should fix this:

```
/'.*?'/
```

Another possibility is to use this:

```
/'[^']*'/
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to do it is:

```
>> %{string = 'aaaa' + string_var_x + 'bbbb' + string_var_y}.scan(/'[^'].+?'/)  
#=> ["'aaaa'", "'bbbb'"]
```

`String.scan` gets overlooked a lot.

Comment: what do you mean _overlooked_?

Comment: People don't even notice it's available, that's what I mean. Is there another meaning?